# multiple threads of QWebView in PyQt4

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, threadpool

Here is the situation: 
I have a class that loads specific url, also have a list of parameters, that I need to send to this url. I want to use threads to load this url kinda 'simultaneously', in other words in stead of loading one QWebView , than finish it than load another one I want to open 5 windows at a time.

OK, So now the problem is, every single window will have different speed, so I need to keep track of what parametrs are in use.

for example:

```
params = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = MyClass(1)
b = MyClass(2)
c = MyClass(3)
```

now if lets say class b has finished befoure other 2 classes, it will get value 4, and will start it again.

And this is sample code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys, signal

class Grabber(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, param=None):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadComplete)
        url = QUrl('http://some website.com/search?param=%s'%param)
        self.load(url)
        self.show()

    def _loadComplete(self):
        print "Done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Dont know what to do with the next 2 lines
    thread_pool = QThreadPool()
    thread_pool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

    param = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] # and so on

    # Whant to achive something similar:
    for i in param:
        a = Grabber(i)
        b = Grabber(i)
        c = Grabber(i)
        d = Grabber(i)
        e = Grabber(i)

    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use threads, ether python native threads or PyQt4 QThread.

Comment: Not sure exactly how it's implemented in Python/PyQt, but it sounds like what you're afer is a queue structure that you can call pop() on to get the next value off the end each time a Grabber finishes its work.  Just make sure you wrap the call to pop() in a thread-lock of some kind (e.g. a mutex) so that only one thread tries to call pop at a time.  Not really an answer (hence in a comment), but should give you some terms to google for a solution ;)

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about it, but sound's great

Comment: @Vor checkout my answer, I edited it to return the `grabber` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something like this works. What this `bookie` class does is store the number of times `loadFinished` is called into the variable `count`, and returns the corresponding item in the list `params`. When creating the `grabber` objects, it maps it to a number through `QSignalMapper`, so you may retrieve the sender of the signal by calling `mapper.mapping(id-of-grabber-object)`. You can go ahead and try this code to see if it works for you before modifying yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, QSignalMapper, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView


class bookie(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(bookie, self).__init__(parent)

        self.count  = 0
        self.url    = 'http://some website.com/search?param={0}'
        self.params = range(100) # instead of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] and so on...

        Grabber = QWebView # This would be your Grabber class

        self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.on_mapper_mapped)

        for grabberNumber in range(10): # Create 10 Grabber instances
            grabber = Grabber()
            grabber.loadFinished.connect(self.mapper.map)

            self.mapper.setMapping(grabber, grabberNumber)

            grabber.loadFinished.emit(True) # Initialize the grabber by emitting loadFinished

    def on_mapper_mapped(self, gNumber):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < len(self.params):
            gParam  = self.params[self.count]   
            grabber = self.mapper.mapping(gNumber)
            #grabber.load(QUrl(self.url.format(gParam)))

            # Next 2 lines for testing purposes, remove & uncomment the previous line

            print "GRABBER:", gNumber, "PARAMETER:", gParam
            QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda:grabber.loadFinished.emit(True)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = bookie()
```

Comment: Can you please take a look, what I did wrong, I opened a new question,because didn't want to do my update to long, so here is the question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960040/open-multiple-webpages-with-different-parametrs-pyqt4`