# Open multiple webpages with different parametrs. PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebview

I have followed the answer by [X.Jacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006989/x-jacobs) on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943558/multiple-threads-of-qwebview-in-pyqt4), and was trying to create an app that will open multiple windows with different parameters, but it doesn't work, looks, like app is opening windows, but not load the webpage.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys, signal

url = 'http://http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t={0}'

class Opener(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, param=None):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.param = param
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.print_title)

    def print_title(self):
        print self.title()

class Foo(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self.params = range(4)
        self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.mapper_mapped)

        for i in range(2):
            opener = Opener()
            opener.loadFinished.connect(self.mapper.map)
            self.mapper.setMapping(opener, i)
            opener.loadFinished.emit(True)
            QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda:opener.loadFinished.emit(True))  

    def mapper_mapped(self, gNumber):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < len(self.params):
            gParam  = self.params[self.count]
            opener = self.mapper.mapping(gNumber)
            opener.load(QUrl(url.format(gParam)))
            opener.show()
            QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda:opener.loadFinished.emit(True)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Foo()
    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
    app_exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on in that code :) checkout this working version and see how you can adapt it to yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Foo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)    

        self.count  = 0
        self.params = range(4)
        self.url    = 'http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t={0}'

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.mapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.on_mapper_mapped)

        for i in range(2):
            grabber = QWebView()
            grabber.loadFinished.connect(self.mapper.map)

            self.mapper.setMapping(grabber, i)
            self.tabWidget.addTab(grabber, "opener {0}".format(str(i)))

            grabber.loadFinished.emit(True)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_mapper_mapped(self, gNumber):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < len(self.params):
            gParam = self.params[self.count]

            opener = self.mapper.mapping(gNumber)
            opener.load(QUrl(self.url.format(gParam)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Foo()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```